# How can Youtube see my viewing history through different circuits?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, cookies

I watch a few videos on Youtube using TB, all about the same or very similar topic. Let's say "topic x".
Then I open a new window in TB, which then will use a different circuit for sites I'm visiting in that window. I watch some videos in this windows, about a different topic.
But this time Youtube will list and recommend me videos about "topic x" on the right side in this new window.
How does Youtube see what I watched in a previous window using a different Tor circuit?

Is it because cookies?
Aren't different windows operate kind of as different "instances"?
How can I prevent this without restarting TB?

I tried to use cookie manager addons and the built-in Firefox cookie manager, but none shows any cookies.
How can I manage cookies in TB? How can I delete cookies set by a certain domain without closing and restarting TB?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When opening a new window, Tor Browser does **not** use a different circuit.
Only restarting tor or clicking on "New Tor Circuit for this site" will change your Exit Node.

If you have disabled cookies and you are connecting through a different circuit, youtube can not be sure that you are the same person.

Comment: Youtube totally can be sure you're the same person even if you've disabled cookies and connecting through a different circuit. Cookies are just the canonicle overt tracking method, there are many other covert tracking methods that a website could deploy which would be just as effective.